# Should players know the details about campaign moves

Tags: dungeon-world

One of the principles of Dungeon World is: Never speak the name of your move. But let's say I have a new general move or a campaign move for the players. For instance a move for a political campaign where players are ambassadors:

> When you **reach a city for the first** time and you **openly declare yourselves as ambassadors of the Emperor**: Roll+Cha. 10+ You are escorted to the ruler of the city with little trouble. 7-9 You are allowed in the city but under a certain condition. The GM will tell you what.

Should players know about moves like that? Should I instead let them roleplay and ask a roll and detail the consequences?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dungeon World has GM moves and player moves.

The GM should never speak the name of a GM move.  The GM should usually relate any custom move that the players are rolling for, whether they be adventure moves, campaign moves, new class moves, etc.

> *Chapter 13, How to GM*
>
> It’s everyone’s responsibility to watch for when a move has been triggered, including you. Stop the players and ask if they mean to trigger the rules when it sounds like that’s what they’re doing.
>
> *Chapter 19, Types of Moves*
>
> Moves for dealing with the environment or special features you’ve added to Dungeon World are special moves. These moves are usually the GM’s domain, a place to make parts of the world stand out. Since moves are always triggered by the players, most moves like this should be written or printed somewhere everyone can look them over unless the move covers something that the player characters wouldn’t have any idea about.

Comment: Great point about sharing campaign move with players. I'd overlooked it.